# how to open a URL with non utf-8 arguments

Tags: python, unicode, urllib, quotes, shift-jis

Using Python I need to transfer non utf-8 encoded data (specifically shift-jis) to a URL via the query string.
How should I transfer the data? Quote it? Encode in utf-8?

Thanks

Comment: unicode is not an encoding, so all urls have non-unicode arguments. I presume you mean non-utf-8.

Comment: thanks for correction - updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query string parameters are byte-based. Whilst IRI-to-URI and typed non-ASCII characters will typically use UTF-8, there is nothing forcing you to send or receive your own parameters in that encoding.

So for Shift-JIS (actually typically cp932, the Windows extension of that encoding):

```
foo= u'\u65E5\u672C\u8A9E' # 日本語
url= 'http://www.example.jp/something?foo='+urllib.quote(foo.encode('cp932'))
```

In Python 3 you do it in the quote function itself:

```
foo= '\u65E5\u672C\u8A9E'
url= 'http://www.example.jp/something?foo='+urllib.parse.quote(foo, encoding= 'cp932')
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what unicode has to do with this, since the query string is a string of bytes. You can use the quoting functions in [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) to quote plain strings so that they can be passed within query strings.

Answer (score 0):

By the »query string« you mean HTTP GET like in `http:/{URL}?data=XYZ`?

You have encoding what ever data you have via `base64.b64encode` using `-_` as alternative character to be URL safe as an option. See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html).

Comment: Base64encode? You should URLEncode it! 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: A matter of taste, isn't it? For arbitrary data I'd stay with Base64. For text content it's more obfuscating but not more confusing than my wrongly edited answer above, which I'm now reading again…